# Asynchronous transfer mode with java

Tags: java, networking, asynchronous, transfer, mode

I'm having troubles with a requirement that have been asked to our company, i will be very thankful if someone can give me a hand on this, the government from my country is asking for every casino to implement a real time data-sending software, for this purpose they gave us a document with the specifications, so here comes the problem, in the document, they request that every data have to be sent using the ATM protocol, but i dont find any example of code in the web about how to implement an application that is able to send data using this protocol, i read some articles, im not sure about it but i think i need an ATM switch for this, my question is..how can i implement the ATM protocol to one JAVA application? Am i right about the ATM switch, and how the data travels using this protocol? do i have to convert it to binary or bytes before? and if you can give me some sample code that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

PD: sorry about my english..is not that good

Answer (score 0):

First you need a *hardware platform* that supports ATM. Then you need a Java API for ATM that is implemented on that hardware. See [ATM Forum Java API specification](http://www.broadband-forum.org/ftp/pub/approved-specs/af-saa-0048.000.pdf), but this is just Googling that you could have done for yourself, and where you are going to get an implementation I have no idea.

Comment: it is a Broken link

Comment: @jafarbtech That is hardly surprising, as it is over five years old. Google is your friend :-|

Comment: do u have some other new links regarding this?

Comment: @jafarbtech No I don't, offhand, but Google does, as I already said. That's how I found this one, as I also already said. You can too, as I *also* already said. You don't need me to play nursemaid over five-year-old SO threads in case their links break.

Comment: ha haa.... No probs bro... I will get it from google as U already said ;)